# PL/SQL Procedure Fetching Tuples in a Loop using Cursor

Tags: plsql, tuples, cursor, fetch, procedure

I am trying to create a procedure that will read 100 tuples from TableA. And for each tuples retrieved from TableA, it will also retrieve the relevant tuple from TableB using the student_ID index and add the required attributes into the memory/record. The tuples with the new attributes will be loaded into the data warehouse. Before loading, it needs to check if the dimension tables already contain the info. If yes, then it will only update the fact table, or otherwise update both tables. Repeat all steps until all the data are loaded into the data warehouse.

Below is my code that's under construction.

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROJ AS
                v_tab_rec varchar2 (100);
                v_counter number (5);
                v_student_id TableB.student_id%type;
                v_studname TableB.studname%type;
                v_address TableB.address%type; 
                v_coursename TableB.coursename%type;
            DECLARE
                CURSOR c_TableA IS
                SELECT * FROM TableA;
                v_tab_rec c_TableA%ROWTYPE;
            BEGIN
                OPEN c_TableA;
                v_counter :=1;
                WHILE (v_counter <= 500)   
                    LOOP
                        FETCH c_TableA INTO v_tab_rec;
                        EXIT WHEN c_TableA%NOTFOUND;
                        
                        SELECT * FROM v_tab_rec WHERE v_tab_rec.student_id = v_TableB.student_id;
                        
                        IF v_tab_rec.student_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Student) THEN
                            INSERT INTO Student VALUES (v_tab_rec.student_ID, v_studname, v_address);
                        ELSIF v_tab_rec.course_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Course) THEN
                            INSERT INTO Course VALUES (v_tab_rec.course_id, v_coursename);
                        ELSIF v_tab_rec.subject_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Subject) THEN
                            INSERT INTO Subject VALUES (v_tab_rec.subject_id, v_tab_rec.subject_name);
                        END IF;
                     END LOOP;
                 END LOOP;
                    IF c_tableA%ISOPEN THEN
                        CLOSE c_tableA;
                    END IF;
                COMMIT;
                v_counter := v_counter +100;
            END PROJ;
            /
```

Comment: Understood but where is the problem ?

Comment: I received compile errors. Do you know if there's any wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is full of errors, both structural (compile time) and logic (run time). Also, your code does not seem to match the description; which itself is confusing. In the following I have attempted to point out the structural errors in your procedure and a  couple comments. See tag ---<<<.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROJ AS
                v_tab_rec varchar2 (100);                 
                v_counter number (5);
                v_student_id TableB.student_id%type;
                v_studname TableB.studname%type;
                v_address TableB.address%type; 
                v_coursename TableB.coursename%type;
            DECLARE  
            ---<<< Declare. Not necessary, or you are sstarting a nested block
            ---<<< This is not an Error, but does have ramafacations later which 
            ---<<< would generate an error.
                CURSOR c_TableA IS
                SELECT * FROM TableA;
                v_tab_rec c_TableA%ROWTYPE;     
                ---<<< v_ab_rec already defined as scalar variable
            BEGIN
                OPEN c_TableA;
                v_counter :=1;
                WHILE (v_counter <= 500) 
                ---<<< Login: Above essentially createa an infinate loop
                ---<<< as v_counter only incremented AFTER loop is complete
                ---<<< so above condition will always remain true. 
                    LOOP
                        FETCH c_TableA INTO v_tab_rec;
                        ---<<< v_tab_rec duplicate definition as Cursor Row type AND Scalar 
                        EXIT WHEN c_TableA%NOTFOUND;
                        
                        SELECT * FROM v_tab_rec WHERE v_tab_rec.student_id = v_TableB.student_id;
                        ---<<< v_tab_rec is NOT a table or view so cannot select from it 
                        ---<<< even if you could INTO clause missing from select. Required in PL/SQL.
                        ---<<< v_TableB is undefined 
                        
                        IF v_tab_rec.student_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Student) THEN
                        ---<<< The "Select *: is invalid as used but even if it were allowed
                        ---<<< it retrieves all columns from student. You cannot compare 
                        ---<<< the scalar v_tab_rec.student_id to the row returned by the select. 
                            INSERT INTO Student VALUES (v_tab_rec.student_ID, v_studname, v_address);
                        ---<<< nor would the above select (if valid) populate the "v_" variables.  
                       
                        ELSIF v_tab_rec.course_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Course) THEN
                        ---<<< Same problems as Student
                            INSERT INTO Course VALUES (v_tab_rec.course_id, v_coursename);
                        
                        ELSIF v_tab_rec.subject_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Subject) THEN
                         ---<<< Same problems as Student
                            INSERT INTO Subject VALUES (v_tab_rec.subject_id, v_tab_rec.subject_name);
                        END IF;
                     END LOOP;
                 END LOOP;
                 ---<<< End second loop, however there is only 1 loop
                    IF c_tableA%ISOPEN THEN
                        CLOSE c_tableA;
                    END IF;
                COMMIT;
                v_counter := v_counter +100;
                ---<<< Why increment after the loop is complete (not an error,
                ---<<< but serves no purpose 
                
            END PROJ;
```

---<<< LOGIC Problem:  
The "If...Elsif...Elsif...End if" allows for any ONE of the 3 tables to not contain the necessary id. But what happens when Student, Course, and Subject are ALL missing the necessary id.

Description is confusing. What is the purpose of "read 100 tuples from TableA" and then trying to exit after processing 500 rows. Further "only update the fact table, or otherwise update both tables" is unclear. What are the fact tables (Student, Course, and Subject?), but what is the other table in "both tables"? What purpose does TableB serve?

Answer (score 0):

This is your code, fixed. As I don't have your tables, I can't compile it myself.

What was wrong about it? Superfluous `DECLARE` and `END LOOP` (commented in code that follows):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROJ
AS
   v_tab_rec     VARCHAR2 (100);
   v_counter     NUMBER (5);
   v_student_id  TableB.student_id%TYPE;
   v_studname    TableB.studname%TYPE;
   v_address     TableB.address%TYPE;
   v_coursename  TableB.coursename%TYPE;

   --   DECLARE                              --> this
   CURSOR c_TableA
   IS
      SELECT * FROM TableA;

   v_tab_rec     c_TableA%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN c_TableA;

   v_counter := 1;

   WHILE (v_counter <= 500)
   LOOP
      FETCH c_TableA INTO v_tab_rec;

      EXIT WHEN c_TableA%NOTFOUND;

      SELECT *
        FROM v_tab_rec
       WHERE v_tab_rec.student_id = v_TableB.student_id;

      IF v_tab_rec.student_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Student)
      THEN
         INSERT INTO Student
              VALUES (v_tab_rec.student_ID, v_studname, v_address);
      ELSIF v_tab_rec.course_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Course)
      THEN
         INSERT INTO Course
              VALUES (v_tab_rec.course_id, v_coursename);
      ELSIF v_tab_rec.subject_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Subject)
      THEN
         INSERT INTO Subject
              VALUES (v_tab_rec.subject_id, v_tab_rec.subject_name);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   --END LOOP;                               --> this

   IF c_tableA%ISOPEN
   THEN
      CLOSE c_tableA;
   END IF;

   COMMIT;
   v_counter := v_counter + 100;
END PROJ;
/
```